# Is it possible to make a new kind of variable that can be different things?

Tags: java, variables

I want to make a new variable with which i can do the following:

```
Variable v1 = 1;
Variable v2 = "Test";
Variable v3 = 7.31;
```

Is this possible, or is this impossible?

Comment: If you want variables that have "duck" or [dynamic typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) consider using a scripting language which is built to handle just this sort of thing. Examples include Ruby, Python and Groovy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take advantage of auto-boxing (Java SE 5.0 and later) then every one of those can be stored in an `Object` (i.e. the base class of all Java types):

```
public class foo {
    static public void main(String[] params) {
        Object v1 = 1;
        Object v2 = "Test";
        Object v3 = 7.31;

        System.out.println(v1 + " " + v1.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println(v2 + " " + v2.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println(v3 + " " + v3.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

output:

```
% java foo
1 java.lang.Integer
Test java.lang.String
7.31 java.lang.Double
```

This does not necessarily make it a good idea, though!

The output shown above shows how although every variable was *declared* as an `Object`, their real class name is one more appropriate for their type.  It's only because *every* class in Java is derived from `Object` that the declarations can work that way.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about the object. Thanks!

Comment: @ROLLER `Object` is the most fundamental class in Java.  You _need_ to know about it!

Comment: I saw things that referenced to it, but never understood what it really does.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Check the code below:

```
    Object a;
    Object b;
    Object c;

    a = 1;
    b = "abc";
    c = 1.72d;
```

or another way:

```
    Object a;

    a = 1;
    a = "abc";
    a = 1.72d;
```

In this case we observe [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html), when a value is wrapped to a suitable object type.

As `Object` class is the parent for all java objects, then we have a way to code as I described above.